# How to get confidence levels(probabilities) for DNN Regressor in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

For DNN Classifier there is a method predict_proba to get the probabilities, whereas for DNN Regressor it is not there. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

In terminal, type `help(tf.contrib.learn.DNNRegressor`. There you will see the object has methods such as `predict()` which returns predicted scores.

DNNRegressor does regression, not classification, so you don't get a probability distribution over classes.

Comment: if DNN Regressor predicts a value/score , is there any way to get the confidence level of that prediction?
The probability that DNN classifier gives, can be seen as the confidence of its prediction for the classes , so in regression cant we get the same.

Comment: No, DNN Regressor will not tell you the confidence of the prediction. You can judge overall confidence based on a validation set.